# NG2339: Property does not exist on type 'Object'

Tags: angular

I try to repeat this code: [code](https://favicon.tech/kak-sozdat-polnostranichnyj-veb-sajt-v-angular-chast-2-4/)

But can't, because returned errors like this:

> src/app/page/page.component.html:1:28 - error NG2339: Property 'image' does not exist on type 'Object'.
>   1
>
> src/app/page/page.component.ts:8:16
>
> 8   templateUrl: './page.component.html',
>
> Error occurs in the template of component PageComponent.

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ContentService } from '../shared/services/content.service';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-page',
  templateUrl: './page.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./page.component.scss']
})
export class PageComponent implements OnInit {
  page: Object;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private contentService: ContentService) { }

ngOnInit() {
  const pageData = this.route.snapshot.data['page'];
  this.page = this.contentService.pages[pageData];
}
}
```

I don't know how fix it. Help please

Comment: Are you calling `page.image` in your html?

Comment: The problem is in your html file as the error says, so you need to post that as well if we are to help you.

Comment: Also what object type does this return? `this.contentService.pages[pageData]` If you have a type for that then page should be that type rather than `Object`.

Comment: What is the value of the `const pageData`? Does the `ContentService` `pages` property contain an object with the value of `const pageData` as it's key?

Answer (score 0):

You have an html error and you don't display the html ?

Don't type you variable as an Object is not advise, type with any.

try this :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ContentService } from '../shared/services/content.service';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-page',
  templateUrl: './page.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./page.component.scss']
})
export class PageComponent implements OnInit {
  page: any;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private contentService: ContentService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    const pageData = this.route.snapshot.data['page'];
    this.page = this.contentService.pages[pageData];
  }
}
```

And in your html to display your variable, try this :

```
{{page?.image}}
```

your welcome if it's work ! :)